# PowerShell script to post the last line of a log file to my Discord server is taking a long time to post messages. How to make it faster?

Tags: powershell, discord

I am using a script on Windows PowerShell to post a message using webhooks on Discord, and it does not post the message instantly when it happens.

The script is below:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\AYYA\.chatty\logs"
$watcher.Filter = "highlighted.log"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $log = "File: $path $changeType"
    $webhookurl = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1183179002920321064/jdy2EO4AdnFhQg_ON9TfwCOPcDo8y1H7TYrQUT0HtCI5a7AO2FOd_As1BYUNWqhI0oei"
    $content = (Get-Content -Path $path -Tail 1).ToString()
        $body = @{
        content = $content
    } | ConvertTo-Json
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $webhookurl -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
    }

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Changed -Action $action
```

How to make it faster?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is, is there a way for it to post it instantly as it happens? since it is taking so long to post on the discord server.

Comment: Just an idea rather than `$content = (Get-Content -Path $path -Tail 1).ToString()` run it as two lines to `$content = Get-Content -Path $path -Tail 1` followed by another line `$content.ToString()` just to see if that makes any difference. How large or how many lines is usually in `$path`? Does testing to get a smaller set of data make any difference?

Comment: It could be the time it takes to detect the file change or the time it takes for the webhook to be processed by discord. Try adding a delay in the script `Start-Sleep -Seconds 1` to give the filesystem a chance to settle first. Also, to isolate if the delay is being caused by the discord webhook, try to remove it from the script and instead simply output to the console with `Write-Host $content` and see if the delay remains, and then take it from there.

Comment: This is a SO programming question. Also, you probably shouldn't include real webhook URL. Did you check if watcher events are executed "instantly" by using something simplier like e.g. Windows notification?

Comment: How long is it taking? If you break down the script steps and run them individually, which ones take the longest? Does that account for all of the time it is taking when run all together?